# what formula can identify an ODD vs EVEN number

Tags: filemaker

what formula can identify an ODD vs EVEN number 
ODD result can be 0
EVEN result can be 1
or vice versa

Comment: Trying to show your code in here so that we can know what your progress is.

Answer (score 2):

The expression:

```
Mod ( YourNumber ; 2 )
```

returns 1 (True) if YourNumber is odd, 0 (False) otherwise.

The expression:

```
not Mod ( YourNumber ; 2 )
```

returns 1 (True) if YourNumber is even, 0 (False) otherwise.